# Unbound Rounded Corner Shaped Ripple - Jetpack Compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ripple-effect

Looking for a way to have unbound ripple I came upon the ripple indication. For example:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false),
            enabled = buttonEnabled,
        ) {
            onDetailClick.invoke()
        },
    text = detailText,
    color = if (buttonEnabled) Theme.colors.primary else Theme.colors.textDisabled,
    style = Theme.typography.bodyMediumSemiBold,
)
```

But the issue is that it's always a circle with the center of the layout, and I can't find any way to have it in a rounded rectangle shape, so it would still be around the Text but also not bounded.
I'll appreciate your opinions and ideas.